# SSL certificate key permission - Tomcat APR

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have an SSL certificate from GoDaddy that I would like to use with my tomcat installation. Currently it is being used by Apache HTTP server without problems.

The private key is stored in /etc/ssl/private and access is restricted. Apache HTTP server however had no problem serving the correct certificate over SSL.

When I try to point tomcat to the same private key it fails to init the secure protocol because it cannot read the private key.
This is the excerpt from my server.xml. I am using APR:

```
<Connector SSLCertificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/mysite.crt"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/ssl/mysite.key"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" port="8443"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1" />
```

This generates an error.
The Apache HTTP configuration looks like this and works:

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key

The permissions for the /etc/private directory were not changed afaik: 
drwx--x--- 2 root ssl-cert  4096 2011-05-01 11:50 private
Inside:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     1,7K 2011-04-30 11:00 mysite.key

Now my question is: How can I make tomcat make use of the same file? My temporary solution is to copy the key file to a publicly accessible place but I believe this is dangerous right?

Thanks

Comment: `This generates an error.` - What is the error?

Comment: The exact error is:
Error initializing endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key (error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssl-cert` group has traverse permissions on `private`, and everyone has read permissions on the key itself - so, the user that Tomcat is running as is likely not a member of the `ssl-cert` group.

Add the user to the group to give it read-only access to the cert:

```
usermod -a -G ssl-cert tomcatusername
```

And, although you've got the directory permissions locked down, which should cover you, you may want to change the permissions on the certificate itself to match (some services check for world-readable on private keys):

```
chown root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key
chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I was confused, however, since the apache user www-data is not part of this group but was stil able to access the file. Also thanks for the hint on the key permissions!

Comment: need chmod 750 /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key